# Correlation Matrix Problem of Three Decomposition Level of DWT

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, wavelets

I'm trying to apply a DWT with 3 composition levels and the following question arose when calculating the composition matrix.
The step I'm trying to follow is:

The DWT coefficientes are obtained from filtering operations and are divided in approximation ($cA$) and detail coefficients ($cD$).

[Three Decomposition Level of DWT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAkxm.png)

If a signal $f(n)$ is scaled up to a defined decomposition level, then, it will be producing a wavelet matrix $M(J+1,n)$, this matrix is analysed using its correlation matrix defined by:

$$
\boldsymbol{Y}=\frac{\boldsymbol{M} \times \boldsymbol{M}^T}{n}
$$

where $n$ is the total sample numbers. Therefore, it has a matrix $Y(J+1,J+1)$ which contains the scaled frequency information of the signal.

Each level of decomposition will have a matrix with a different size, so how am I going to analyze the correlation matrix? Should it be done individually? Should I complete with zeros? Should I only analyze $cD_3$ AND $cA_3$?

For example, for a discrete signal that I am applying. It will first generate a $cD_1$  (9x1), $cD_2$  (6x1), $cD_3$ (4x1) and $cA_3$ (4x1).

Each coefficient has a different size.